# HTML anchor replace with RegEx

Tags: c#, html, regex, replace

I have HTML data which I'll be using in a client app. I need to Regex.Replace the `<a>` tags from

```
<a href="Bahai.aspx">Bahai</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#" onclick="process('Bahai.aspx');return false;">Bahai</a>
```

In **C#** using RegExReplace with a regex similar to

```
<a[^>]*? href=\"(?<url>[^\"]+)\"[^>]*?>(?<text>.*?)</a>
```

Ideas?

Comment: I bet C# has some kind of HTML parser you should better use instead of regular expressions. By the way, you should also use `href="Bahai.asp" onclick="process(this.href); return false"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# you could use code like this:

```
Regex.Replace("<a href=\"Bahai.aspx\">Bahai</a>", 
            "<a href=\"(.+?)\">(.+?)</a>", "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"process('$1');return false;>$2</a>",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

It will return a string that matches what you require.

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. `Process` is not the same as `process`. You also don’t need the label `javascript`.

Comment: I agree with you, I'd just copy pasted from the question which has now changed :-) The RegexOptions.IgnoreCase is used to ignore the case of the input string, so this will work with <A HREF... and <a href...

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's best not to parse HTML with regular expressions. Try the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using javascript to get people to visit Bahai.aspx, then people without javascript won't get there. Could you use javascript to do the rewrite instead, for instance in jquery?

Let's say you tag the anchor tags with `class="doProcess"` then you could use the following jQuery script to change the links:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.doProcess').each(function(){
    var a = $(this);
    var href = a.attr('href');
    a.attr('href','#');
    a.click(function(){
      process(href);
      return false;
    });
  });
});
```

then both the users with javascript and without will get sent to Bahai (if that is what your process method does) :)